# how to change a numeric data to text in pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two bars in that I plotted from a csv column. The column name is 'sex' and the values are 0 for male and 1 for female. this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df['sex'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

I want instead of having 0 and 1 for each bar, I would like to change it the 'Male' and 'Female' respectively.
The output I get is: 
[image: my plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to manually add costumized labels:

```
p = df['sex'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
p.set_xticklabels(['Male','Female'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code:

```
df['sex'] = np.where(df['sex'] == 0, 'male', 'female')
```

Comment: a nice faster alternative to `df.sex.apply(lambda x: ...)`

Answer (score 1):

before plotting, you can change the value in the dataframe like this:

```
df.sex = df.sex.apply(lambda x: 'Male' if x == 0 else 'Female')
```

Then the plot will apply those labels.